# VPN tunnel connection issue

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, ipsec

My company has 2 ASA firewall with model 5510 & 5512 in difference country, I was connected it via IPSEC VPN. It can work in normal until 2 weeks ago.

I checked from log in ASA5512 firewall, it has error message :

```
Tunnel Manager has failed to establish an L2L SA.  All configured IKE versions 
failed to establish the tunnel. Map Tag= outside_map.  Map Sequence Number = 1.
```

And this message only display in ASA5512 and haven't alert in ASA5510. Also, the problem only affected specified tunnel only, remain other IPSEC VPN tunnel able to work properly.

I ran `show isakmp sa` on both firewall it shows:

```
IKE Peer: [Firewall IP Address]
Type    : user            Role    : initiator 
Rekey   : no              State   : MM_WAIT_MSG2
```

It look IKE phase 1 is unable to connect on each other.

Does anyone can advise on this issue?

Comment: Something must have changed in one of the configurations.  Can you compare the current configuration to a previous one?  Or, can you post the configurations of each (remove sensitive info first)?

Comment: Thanks Ron,

I was tried restore old configure file to it but no help. Afterward I removed those configure in both side ASA then recreate it, it able to connect right now.

Will keep monitor to it and thanks for your reply.

Best Regards

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.